# Android viewpager background with fixed footer

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a fixed footer at the bottom of a ViewPager. I want the background of the ViewPager to overflow behind the fixed footer but yet have any content in the ViewPager not overflow behind the fixed footer. Is this even possible? I have the following layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/wizard_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_separator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/wizard_previous"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/indicator_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <Button
            android:id="@+id/wizard_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: I've tried to play with the layout_height of the ViewPager but I either get the background and all content overflowing behind the fixed footer or neither the color nor content overflowing behind the footer. Wondering if I need to create a custom ViewPager for this sort of thing...

Comment: You will only get this by adding a great bottom oadding for your content inside the viewpager, why you cant make the viewpager fills the rest of the screen above the button?

Comment: I believe that your idea of fixing the bottom padding for the fragments inside the ViewPager is the right way to go with this. Is it possible to dynamically do this sort of thing so I don't have to add the padding the every fragment? Meaning, can the ViewPager itself set the bottom padding before adding the fragments?

Comment: So I won't have access to the source for the individual fragments that are added to the ViewPager. Is there some way that the ViewPager itself or the FragmentPagerAdapter can set the bottom margins of all the fragments?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using RecyclerView as parent to your viewPager and your footer this will help.
The last view that sits at the bottom of your view should have its android:layout_alignParentBottom attribute set to true
and then give it the same or more distance to the bottom of your parent layout than the height of your footer with android:layout_marginBottom